# Implement cursor based pagination using pothos and prisma

Tags: graphql, prisma, prisma-graphql

Is there any way to implement cursor-based pagination using the `pothos` `Prisma plugin`, I'm referring to [this plugin](https://pothos-graphql.dev/docs/plugins/prisma) .but there is no clear example of how to do the pagination. The documentation is somewhat difficult to understand. this is the `Prisma` model I want for the pagination

Prisma Model

```
model user {
      id String @id @map("_id")
      factories factory[] 
      @@map("user")
    }
```

Pothos Model

```
builder.prismaObject("user", {
          fields: (t) => ({
            id: t.exposeID("id"),
            factories:t.relation("factories")
        }),
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the way to do the cursor-based pagination using pothos. you just have to add the `prismaConnection` to the `query field`

```
builder.queryField("users", (t) =>
  t.prismaConnection({
    type: "user",
    cursor: "id",
    resolve: async (query, _root, _args, _ctx, _infu) => {
      // add the relevant cursors-based Prisma pagination logic 
      // here.you can refer to the Prisma 
      // doc for more info
      return await db.user.findMany({ ...query });
    },
  })
);
```

this will automatically add all the `cursours,edges,nodes` and `pageInfo` Objects to the response